# In mac terminal, how to check which port mysql is running?

Tags: mysql, terminal, port, netstat

I've done some research and found several places where people suggest using `netstat` to check which port a particular process is using. 
But here is what I got:

```
myMac:~/Documents$ netstat -ap tcp | grep -i "listen"

tcp4       0      0  localhost.mysql        *.*                    LISTEN
```

What does `localhost.mysql` say about the port number?? I'm expecting a 4 digit number like 3306. 
Any thoughts?

Comment: numbers are converted to names. /etc/services has a mapping. Adding `-n` to netstat will prevent conversion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use -n for netstat to show network addresses as numbers.

```
netstat -nap tcp | grep -i "listen"
```

```
man netstat
-n Show network addresses as numbers (normally netstat interprets addresses and attempts to display them symbolically).  This option may be used with any of the display formats.
```

Or use lsof:

```
lsof -n -P -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN
```

Or use mysql client to check mysql port:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a note: `netstat -nap tcp | grep -i 'listen'` would't work since you can't tell which one is mysql from the results - the results are all numbers and there is no string to identify for mysqld. But the other solutions work.

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C yep, use -n shows numbers(port), and without -n shows **localhost.mysql**, combine the results can identify the mysql port.

Comment: I use: `lsof -n -P -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN | grep mysql`

Comment: Only the last solution worked for me. The first does not show what is mysql. The second failed to identify a running mysql server. Perhaps something to do with running mysql via preferences panel in macos (Monterey).

Answer (score 1):

if you have Workbench installed then just open it and check the port. most likely, it will be 3306.
see screenshot attached [image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your process is running as a LaunchDaemon you will need to use sudo to see it.

> sudo lsof -n -P -i TCP -s TCP:LISTEN